# how to configure web server properly with router

Tags: web, dns, webserver, ip

Facts:
I have the public ip address of my router that is static that i got from my ISP(internet service provider). 
I also have a web server with windows server 2008 r2 edition.
I have my domain pointed at the public ip address of the router.

Question:

how do i set the web server up, with the router, to manage requests to the website.

Example:
i need to know how to do this:

When someone enters my domain name into their web browser , the DNS server sends them to the ip address of my router, then my router sends them to my web server to display my web site.

Comment: Static port mapping on the router for port 80 to be forwarded to you web server.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your routers settings (most routers its 192.181.1.1 but look under your router for yours)
Type in your username and password (also located under the router) and once in find the port fowarding settings.

Have it foward all port 80 traffic to the ip address of your computer. So if your computers ip is 192.168.1.3 make it direct traffic to that ip.

Comment: actually i have a access point not a router. will that make a difference?

Comment: Should be almost identical but I have never set it up with a access point before. Google says they are almost identical [Difference between Router and Access Point](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-wireless-networking-41/difference-between-access-point-and-wireless-router-203886/)

Comment: Then why does you question say router?

Answer (score 1):

Your router does port based natting for traffic from your inside 192.x.x.x network and the outside internet using your public IP. 
What you want to do is called reverse NAT. For that you have to define a mapping of your internal IP and port number to an external IP and port number. It looks something like this

`X.X.X.X:80 ------------> 192.168.1.x:80`

X.X.X.X is your public IP and 192.168.1.x is the ip of machine where you are running webserver. Once you have this mapping it will let outside traffic to come inside using reverse NAT. 
Most of the router have this feature listed as port forwarding where you have to create this type of mapping. They will ask you external port and internal ip and port to map to.
-MS